# Dovecot SQL Query Error - Why?

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, dovecot

```
SELECT CONCAT('maildir:/var/vmail/',maildir) AS mail,
       5000 AS uid, 
       5000 AS gid 
FROM mailbox 
INNER JOIN domain 
WHERE username = 'test@example.com'
  AND mailbox.active = '1'
  AND domain.active = '1'
```

What's wrong with this query? Postgresql says:

```
'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE" 
LINE 1: ...S uid, 5000 AS gid FROM mailbox INNER JOIN domain WHERE user...'
```

Comment: `DOMAIN` is a word used in the syntax. Try to avoid using it as an identifier, or quote it (for the rest of your life) with double quotes.

Comment: @wildplasser MySQL used backquotes for disambiguation, isn't it valid for postgres?

Comment: No, Postgres (and the SQL standard) require(s) double quotes (`"DOMAIN"` ) The backticks are a mysql invention. (BTW: the `JOIN` still needs an `ON ...` clause, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT CONCAT('maildir:/var/vmail/',maildir) AS mail,
       5000 AS uid,
       5000 AS gid
FROM mailbox
INNER JOIN DOMAIN on
  username = 'test@example.com'
  AND mailbox.active = '1'
  AND DOMAIN.active = '1'
```